# Reversing an Array in Assembly (masm)

Tags: assembly, masm

I am trying to reverse an array in assembly but I am not being able to successfully do so. The program worked fine for double words but isn't working now for words. I checked it using the visual studio debugger. The final result is 98,78,10,00,36 which is wrong. My code is

```
.386
.model flat,stdcall
ExitProcess PROTO,dwExitCode:DWORD
.data

intarray WORD 10h,20h,36h,78h,98h

.code
main PROC


mov esi,OFFSET intarray
mov edi,OFFSET intarray
add edi,SIZEOF intarray
sub edi,TYPE intarray
mov ecx,LENGTHOF intarray/2




L1:
mov eax,[ESI]
mov ebx,[EDI]
mov [EDI],eax
mov[ESI],ebx
add esi,TYPE intarray
sub edi,TYPE intarray
loop L1

invoke ExitProcess,0
main ENDP 
END main
```

Comment: Try searching on this [extremely common problem](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=reverse+array+%5Bassembly%5D).  One bug in your code is that you're loading / storing dwords but your array is words.

Comment: I didn't find it anywhere.

Comment: That's why I asked. I don't just "love" asking questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're moving DWORDS (4 bytes). A word is 2 bytes.

You should get the correct results by changing the code to something like:

```
mov ax,[ESI]
mov bx,[EDI]
mov [EDI],ax
mov [ESI],bx
```

Or with one instruction and one register less:

```
mov ax,[ESI]
xchg ax,[EDI]
mov [ESI],ax
```

Comment: why would you suggest `xchg` with memory?  It has an implicit `lock` prefix.  You don't need a slow atomic read-modify-write for this, so it's much faster to just use the existing code with separate loads/stores (of the right size).

Comment: It's 6 bytes less and uses one less register. Different code sequences have different applications.